# Error in time of installing Oracle 12: Failed to add <user> install user to %2% group

Tags: oracle12c

I was trying to install `oracle 12c` on Windows 10 but I got an error `Failed to add "user" install to %2% group"`.

[image: Error description]

Note that I run the setup process as an administrator.

How can the issue be resolved?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use Oracle Database Express Edition. That works for me.
[Download from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html).